# Sich befreunden vs. sich anfreunden

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> In Chaträumen zu sprechen, ist eine Gute Art und Weise, Leute zu finden, mit denen man **sich anfreunden** kann.
>
> In Chaträumen zu sprechen, ist eine Gute Art und Weise, Leute zu finden, mit denen man **sich befreunden** kann.

Meine Frage ist : Wann kann man `sich befreunden` verwenden, nicht `sich anfreunden` und was ist der Unterschied dazwischen? Danke!

Comment: "befreunden" wird als Verb [kaum mehr verwendet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=befreunden&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbefreunden%3B%2Cc0). Das Partizip "befreundet" ist allerdings gebräuchlich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich würde immer "sich mit jemandem anfreunden" verwenden, wenn es um den Vorgang geht.

"Mit jemandem befreundet sein" beschreibt den Zustand, nachdem man Freunde geworden ist, oder sich angefreundet hat.

Im übertragenen Sinne kann man sich auch mit einer Situation anfreunden, d.h., man arrangiert sich mit der Lage, man gibt seine negative Haltung auf und findet sich damit ab oder gewinnt ihr positive Aspekte ab.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung